# How to export data from odbc?

Tags: mysql, database, odbc

I'm a newbie for odbc. Right now I'm connecting odbc successfully to mysql. Is there any way to easily export datatable to the local? (For me, access is not an option. And I have tried odbc explorer which is good but there's only free trial version. Also I have tried Mysql workbench, which is too dangerous since it can easily wipe out all data in the source.)

Hope to have some suggestions from you guys, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases I know have some import/export utilites. Such tools exports both schema (tables descriptions, triggers, user functions etc) and data. Of course they are made to work with the same database engine or to move data to newer version of database engine. Mysql have such tools too: look at [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

From ODBC you can obtain some information about schema: table names, column names, column types, primary key etc, and that information should be enough to make simple utility to export data to local files, for example into .csv files. Simply read info about tables using [SQLTables()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711831%28VS.85%29.aspx), then for each table do `SELECT * FROM table` and write result into `.csv` file.